# Request to reopen 396626 (How do I stop this message?)

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

Could someone please reopen this question:

[How do I stop this message?](https://superuser.com/questions/396626/how-do-i-stop-this-message)

These repeated `launchd` error messages being reported to Console.app in Mac OS X is a perfectly real question, which has an answer: the one I provided.

Look, I realize that if you are approaching this question coming from a Windows software perspective and background, a one line question like the following, with no other information, would be ridiculous (i.e. in which of the trillions of apps for Windows are you seeing this error message?):

`3/3/12 3:35:03.002 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503: (com.hp.help.tocgenerator) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds`

Coming from a Mac perspective, I new immediately where he or she is seeing these messages, as there’s only one place, in `Console.app`:

[image]

(As you can see, I have several similar messages myself).

If the question were still open, I could improve the wording of it to provide the information on where he/she is seeing it (which if it had been there in the first place, I would certainly hope this question wouldn’t have been closed).

Comment: you can still improve while closed. That's the point of closure, give it a chance to be fixed before it gets deleted.

Comment: @Sathya's correct. NSGod, why don't you edit the question to improve it, and once your edit is approved, people can consider reopening it.

Comment: @Sathya: Ugh, what the heck. At some point, for some reason, I got the impression that I couldn’t edit the post because it was closed, but that’s clearly not the case (think I was looking at the Revisions page or something). I’ve edited it now (which needs approval because of my rank) to help clarify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original question was fairly vague, [a sentiment shared by 5 users](https://superuser.com/posts/396626/revisions), some of them [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx) users & voted to close them. You may recognize the problem because you've been in a similar situation, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's a good question. Also, it helps to have a cool mind and not blast about people for question closure.

Having said that, closure of a question is not the end of the world. Anyone can propose edits and shape a bad question into a reasonably good question.

You have done that, I've approved the edit & reopened the question